# NextJS 13 fails to fetch from internal api route when deploying

Tags: mongodb, next.js, server, fetch-api, next.js13

When fetching from /api in npm run dev or npm run build/start my code is working, but when try to deploy it on Vercel it fails to fetch. Im using Next js 13 with app dir.

here is my code on the client (server component)

```
const getAvailableSlots = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(
    `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_URL}/api/availabilityList`
  );
  if (!res.ok) {
    console.log(res);
  }

  return res.json();
};

const Appointments = async () => {
  const data = await getAvailableSlots();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div>
        <AppointmentsPage data={data} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Appointments;
```

and this is the /api route:

```
const handler = async (req, res) => {
  await connectDB();
  console.log("Connected to Mongo");
  try {
    const availiblityList = await Users.find();
    res.status(200).send(availiblityList);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error.message);
  }
};

export default handler;
```

I tried directly accessing the data from the server since its server components, but in development mode it loads on the first time with warning that only can pass down simple object as props and can't reload after that.

```
import { getData } from "../../pages/api/availabilityList";

const getAvailableSlots = async () => {
  const res = await getData();
  return res;
};

const Appointments = async () => {
  const data = await getAvailableSlots();
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="section section0 fp-auto-height-responsive items-center">
        <AppointmentsPage data={data} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Appointments;
```

/api

```
export async function getData() {
  await connectDB();

  const response = await Users.find();
  return response;
}

const handler = async (req, res) => {
  const jsonData = await getData();
  res.status(200).json(jsonData);
};

export default handler;
```

The Warning:

```
Warning: Only plain objects can be passed to Client Components from Server Components.    Objects with toJSON methods are not supported. Convert it manually to a simple value before passing it to props. [{$__: ..., $isNew: false, _doc: ...}, ...]
```

^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: Please simplify your code. Does this help? https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/data-fetching/get-static-props#write-server-side-code-directly

Comment: Thank you for the comment, however I wasn't able to solve it through the docs. I've narrowed it down to essentially when fetching from http://localhost:3000 api in development, what url should I use as the environment variable for production in Vercel? Cheers

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Don't fetch client-side from your server. If you need your public API internally too, refactor the logic in a helper function/module and use it directly. And you should be able to produce a minimal working version of your idea. Start with a simple hello world API route, use it and work your way up.

Comment: currently I am facing the same issue but it's not even working locally

Comment: The community already declared that The App Router is currently in beta and we do not recommend using it in production.

you can verify this here:
 https://beta.nextjs.org/docs#introducing-the-app-router

Answer (score 6):

I am having the same issue with Route Handlers. I have solved it directly accessing the data from the server as you said.
The warning is a React bug as discussed here (https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/47447). You can avoid it doing this

```
import { getData } from "../../pages/api/availabilityList";

const getAvailableSlots = async () => {
  const res = await getData();
  return res;
};

const Appointments = async () => {
  const data = await JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(await getAvailableSlots()));
  console.log(data);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <div className="section section0 fp-auto-height-responsive items-center">
        <AppointmentsPage data={data} />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Appointments;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work with serverSideProps() or in the new App Router server page() (nextjs 13).

If you're trying to pass a complex object to a client component, you'll need to convert the complex properties to simple values first. Im using MongoDB. Here's an example of how you might do that:

```
    const data = {
      _id: {}, // assuming this is a MongoDB ObjectId or similar
      bucketName: "...",
      userId: {}, // assuming this is a MongoDB ObjectId or similar
      content: "...",
      href: "..."
    };

    // Convert the complex properties to simple values
    const simpleData = {
      _id: data._id.toString(), // convert ObjectId to string
      bucketName: data.bucketName,
      userId: data.userId.toString(), // convert ObjectId to string
      content: data.content,
      href: data.href
    };
```

Now you can pass `simpleData` to your client component.

If you have an array of objects, you can use the map function to convert each object in the array to a simpler form. Here's an example:

```
    //const siteResponse = await collection.find({userId: new ObjectId(user._id)});
    //const sites = siteResponse.toArray();
    //this is an array of objects like this
    const sites = [
      {_id: {}, bucketName: "...", userId: {}, content: "...", href: "..."},
      {_id: {}, bucketName: "...", userId: {}, content: "...", href: "..."},
      // more objects...
    ];

    // Convert each object in the array
    const simpleDataArray = sites.map(data => ({
      _id: data._id.toString(), // convert ObjectId to string
      bucketName: data.bucketName,
      userId: data.userId.toString(), // convert ObjectId to string
      content: data.content,
      href: data.href
    }));
```

Now you can pass `simpleDataArray` to your client component.

Example: